# Meteor JS: How do I insert a document into a collection, but only on the client-side?

Tags: javascript, collections, meteor

I'm new to Meteor and building a simple app to learn the framework. The app I'm building let's you place words on an image of a kitten.

**The desired behavior is this:**

A user clicks anywhere on the kitten, and a contenteditable element appears letting the user enter text. Clicking outside of the element saves the element, and it remains in place.

**The problem I'm running into:**

If I have two browser windows opened with the app, and I click on one kitten in one window, an empty field appears in both windows. Ideally, the empty field would appear only on the window I clicked on. Once a word is saved, then in should be visible in both windows.

**My question:**

Is there a way to `insert` a document into a collection on the client-side only, and then use `upsert` later to add the document to servert-side collection?

**Here's what I tried:**

I created a stub method that exists only on the client-side for inserting the document. The problem with this, is that when I click on the image, an empty field appears for a split-second, and then disappears again.

**Here's the code:**

*image-tags.js*

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  var isEditing;

  Template.image.image_source = function () {
    return "http://placekitten.com/g/800/600";
  };

  Template.tag.rendered = function(){
    var tag = this.find('.tag');
    if (isEditing && !tag.innerText) {
      tag.focus();
    }
  }

  Template.image.events({
    'click img' : function (e) {
      if (isEditing) {
        isEditing = false;
      } else {
        isEditing = true;
        var mouseX = e.offsetX;
        var mouseY = e.offsetY;

        // Tags.insert({x:mouseX, y:mouseY});

        // Insert tag on the client-side only.
        // Upsert later when the field is not empty.
        Meteor.call('insertTag', {x:mouseX, y:mouseY});
      }
    },

    'click .tag' : function (e) {
      isEditing = true;
    },

    'blur .tag' : function (e) {
      var currentTagId = this._id;
      var text = e.target.innerText;

      if(text) {
        Tags.upsert(currentTagId, {$set: {name: text}});
      } else {
        Tags.remove(currentTagId);
      }
    }
  });

  Template.image.helpers({
    tags: function() {
      return Tags.find();
    }
  });

  // Define methods for the collections
  Meteor.methods({
    insertTag: function(attr) {
      Tags.insert({x:attr.x, y:attr.y});
    }
  });
}

// Collections
Tags = new Meteor.Collection('tags');
```

*image-tags.html*

```
<head>
  <title>Image Tagger</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> image}}
</body>

<template name="image">
  <figure>
    <img src="{{image_source}}" />
    <figcaption class="tags">
        {{#each tags}}
          {{> tag}}
        {{/each}}
      </figcaption>
  </figure>
</template>


<template name="tag">
  <div class="tag" contenteditable style="left: {{x}}px; top: {{y}}px;">
    {{name}}
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should store the temporary tag (and probably your `isEditing` var) in `Session`:

```
Session.set("isEditing", true);
Session.set("newTag", {x:mouseX, y:mouseY});
```

You can also create a local collection by passing `null` instead of a collection name when initializing it. However, `Session` should work for what you're doing. Check out the [leaderboard](https://www.meteor.com/examples/leaderboard) for an example.

Edit:

```
<figcaption class="tags">
  {{#each tags}}
    {{> tag}}
  {{/each}}
  {{#with newTag}}
    {{> tag}}
  {{/with}}
</figcaption>

Template.image.newTag = function() {
  return Session.get("newTag");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I just checked out the leaderboard, but not really understanding what you mean by "passing `null` instead of collection" name. Here is the latest build of my app: http://image-tagger.meteor.com/. You can observe how a empty field appears in both browser windows of the app, when you first click on the kitten. If I store the temporary tag information in `Session`, how would I get an empty field to still appear when I click on an image, in only one browser?

Comment: A local collection is defined like `var MyLocalCollection = new Meteor.Collection(null);`. See my edit for a possible way to add the temporary `Session` tag.

Comment: Ah I see, that example really helps. Will give it a try. Thank you!

Comment: Looking more closely, it looks like what you're suggesting is including an empty tag in the DOM, before the user clicks on the image, instead of after. The click event, therefore, should show/hide the tag. And when the tag is saved, the tag element would get replaced with the "real" one?

Comment: If you use a `{{#with newTag}}` block, the tag won't be added to the DOM until the `newTag` helper returns something other than `null`/`undefined`. So you do `Session.set("newTag", {x:mouseX, y:mouseY})` in the click handler, and then do `Session.set("newTag", null)` when you want the temporary tag HTML to go away.

Answer (score 0):

If you create the collection on client-side only you might have problem if you are disconnected : your new docs won't be stored on server.

To my mind the best way is to set a property "published" or "editing" or "status" (with value published / eiditing / ...) in your document.
Then your publish methods should return :

1. All the documents of the current user
2. All the documents "published" or not in "editing" status

When a user create a document it's stored on server but with the editing status.
then when you save you can decide to publish it, and then all other user will receive the document in their subscription.

Hope that alternative solution will help you